# calling c++ functions in c causes fatal error

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, compilation

I have a function written in c++ and declare it using extern "C" as below.
vectors are used inside the test().

test.hpp

```
#include <vector>
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void test();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And calling it in C code as below:

```
#include "test.hpp"
void main(){
   test();
}
```

c++ code compiles fine using g++, while compiling c with GCC, I'm getting No such file or directory error.

```
fatal error: vector: No such file or directory
   16 | #include <vector>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: The `<vector>` header file is a C++ specific header file. It shouldn't be included in a C file. In this case, where you don't even use `std::vector`, why include `<vector>` at all?

Comment: this is a trimmed down version of the actual code,  vectors are used in test().

Comment: So include the `<vector>` header in the C++ source file instead of the C++ header file? Or perhaps better yet, split your `test.hpp` into two parts: One C++-specific part named `test.hpp` and one that can be used from both C and C++ named `test.h`? Then `test.hpp` could include `test.h`, if needed.

Comment: So vector should be included in the `test.cpp` file, not in the  `test.h` file.

Comment: Moving <vector> to source file did the trick, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What should I do in case vector is an argument?

Comment: if the vector is an argument you can't call it from c so it doesn't belong in your c-specific header file